# Visual studio error C2027

Tags: c++, visual-studio, sdl, sdl-2

I am working on my game engine and i get some error which i dont know how to fix. 
I have Camera which have pointer to GameObject but whenever i use him it said that it is undefined type GameObject. I work at Visual studio 2017 and it give me error C2027.

I already have forward declarating and pointer is assigned to object right in constructor. I look on this page but 
Thx for any help.

here is camera.h

```
#pragma once

#include <SDL.h>

#include <SDL_image.h>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>

class GameObject;

#include "Camera_manager.h"
#include "gameObject.h"
#include "Interface_SDL.h"
#include "Layer_manager.h"

#include "Vector2f.h"
#include "Typedef.h"



class Camera : public Interface_SDL
{
public:
    Camera(float relativeX, float relativeY, GameObject* ownerObject, ScreenDestination screenDestination, float cameraResolutionWidth, float cameraResolutionHeight, Layer_manager* layerManager);
    ~Camera();

    //Pozice kamery
    Vector2f _relativeLocation;
    //Object kde je umístěna    
    GameObject* _ownerObject;

    bool active;


    float _cameraResolutionWidth;
    float _cameraResolutionHeight;

    inline float getCameraResolutionWidth() { return _cameraResolutionWidth; }
    inline float getCameraResolutionHeight() { return _cameraResolutionHeight; }



    //Getter pro rozměry kamery v rozmezí 0 - 1
    float getCameraWidthInPercent() { return _screenDestination.XEnd - _screenDestination.XStart; }
    float getCameraHeightInPercent() { return _screenDestination.YEnd - _screenDestination.YStart; }
    //Vrací pozici na obrazovce
    inline float getScreenXstart() {return _screenDestination.XStart * Interface_SDL::_windowWidth; }
    inline float getScreenYstart() { return _screenDestination.YStart * Interface_SDL::_windowHeight; }

    ScreenDestination _screenDestination;
    Layer_manager* _layerManager;
    //getter of LayerManager
    Layer_manager* getLayerManger() { return _layerManager;}

    inline Vector2f getWorldPos() { return _relativeLocation + _ownerObject->getWorldLocation(); }
    inline float getWorldPosX() { return _relativeLocation.GetX() + _ownerObject->getWorldLocation().GetX(); }
    inline float getWorldPosY() { return _relativeLocation.GetY() + _ownerObject->getWorldLocation().GetY(); }



    SDL_Texture* getTexture(int layerNumber);

    //Věco pro mazání textur
    SDL_Texture* cleaningTexture;
    SDL_Rect* cleaningRect;


    //LAYERY
    SDL_Texture* textureLayer0;
    SDL_Texture* textureLayer1;
    SDL_Texture* textureLayer2;
    SDL_Texture* textureLayer3;
    SDL_Texture* textureLayer4;
    SDL_Texture* textureLayer5;
    SDL_Texture* textureLayer6;
    SDL_Texture* textureLayer7;
    SDL_Texture* textureLayer8;
    SDL_Texture* textureLayer9;


    //Funkce pro správu textur

    //Vyčistí všechny Layery a nastaví je na NO USED
    void clearAllLayers();

    //Vyčistí texturu která se vloží
    void clearTexture(SDL_Texture* texture);

    //resize layers
    void resizeLayers(int width, int height);





    void handleEvents();
    void update();

};
```

Comment: ***it give me error C2027*** Always include the exact text of the error message. Most users will have to use google to figure out what C2027 is. Is best to copy error messages from the Output Tab of Visual Studio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler obviously has right :D.

You had a forwar declaration of `GameObject` that is fine. What is not fine is here:

```
inline Vector2f getWorldPos() { return _relativeLocation + _ownerObject->getWorldLocation(); }
```

How can know the compiler that `_ownerObject` has a method `getWorldLocation`?

You need or to include `GameObject` definitions or delcare that function inside cpp file and include the right headers.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `_ownerObject` inside the header file.

The reason is that you only **forward declare** its type using `class GameObject;`. The forward declaration only tells the compiler about the class existing, not how it looks like (that would be done by include "GameObject.h"). Therefore the compiler cannot know if `_ownerObject->getWorldLocation()` in your header line

```
return _relativeLocation + _ownerObject->getWorldLocation();
```

is a valid function call.

To solve this move all functions using `_ownerObject` to the cpp file.